# Find and Replace Hyperlinks from word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, ms-word

Here is my Code....

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application applicationObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDDoc = applicationObject.Documents.Open(FileName: FilePath);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlinks links = aDDoc.Hyperlinks;

for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{
    object index = (object)i;
    string c = links[index].Target; //Here i am getting Com exception, see below
}
```

Com exception: the inner exception is null, Where the link count iam getting correct. Please tell me if any one have the idea how to retrieve the Hyperlink URL.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you paste the origin message of the com exception error.

Comment: links[i]' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' it's giving file not found exception where my path is "C:\Users\gojoseph\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test\UpdatedDoc\ACOM Acom test.docx" when iam going through run its opening the correct file but its showing file not found here.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue but resolved using below code correction.

Instead of using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
```

use this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= links.Count; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string c = links[i].Target
```

Should work fine.

Comment: No its not working in that way getting com exception error. And showing inner exception as null, while its giving the the correct count.

Comment: Are you sure you want the [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.hyperlink.target(v=office.11).aspx)? That's not the URL.

Comment: Yes i want the target only.

Comment: Are you **sure**? Did you read the link about what the target *is*?

Comment: yes i have given it to www.google.com, now i want to get this url one by one. if this is wrong it should not give the count which is absolutely correct.

Comment: I give up. A last time, **read the link:** [LINK HERE, CLICK IT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.hyperlink.target(v=office.11).aspx). Target is **not** the URL. You don't want `Target`.

Comment: k i got it..thanks                                                but the problem is here now links[i]' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' it's giving file not found exception where my path is "C:\Users\gojoseph\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test\Test\UpdatedDoc\ACOM Acom test.docx" when iam going through run its opening the correct file but its showing file not found here.

Comment: @user3480087 can you remove white spaces from the file name and try to execute ?

Comment: @Prokopchuk Vitaliy No, its not working i changed the name like this "ACOMAcomtest.docx". Actually i am downloading it from sharepoint and i put it into a folder and before reading it i closed all the process of "winword" and after that i opened the document and i started reading it where it is giving the correct number of hyperlinks present in the document mean while its not giving the target or address.

Comment: Finally Solved...for (int i = 1; i <= links.Count; i++)
                {                    
                    Hyperlink hlink = links.get_Item(i);
                }

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
            foreach (Hyperlink link in links)
            {
                string c = link.Target;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Replace+or+Modify+Hyperlinks) is an example, where all fields' (all hyperlinks are fields) starting nodes are selected and then are executed in way you want. Check if you get the same com exception error on line with calling `.Target` property.

Comment: That seems to be a third-party API, not the com interop classes that the OP is using.

Comment: @nvoigt I just proposed to try, because if it works fine, OP can look into the realization to find out how to do same, or just use it.